# how can we date mask a text field using javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a text field for date. Now i would like to mask this text field so that a user can input only date value. I even found a [jQuery plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for this. But that doesn't seems to help, as you can input 22/22/2222 in the field that too is accepted by this plugin, which is obviously not a valid date. What is the possible solution?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482064/can-i-create-date-entry-control-with-date-separator-for-classic-asp/5490237#5490237

Answer (score 2):

try working from this http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

if that does not work, try adapting from this code, changing ti to work for your months:

```
    function isZipKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 45))
        return false;

    return true;
    }

    onkeypress="return isZipKey(this);"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the input to be readonly, and put a div around it that has the onclick set to call the calendar.

That way they can't change the value, but if they click on it they can set a new date.

Comment: @James: good answer but obviously not acceptable.   
i want to mask the field. i don't want user to navigate through the calendar to select what he can write easily. Infact i can leave the plan of masking the input but cannot forbid the user to input manually.

Comment: So just use keypress events and validate each keypress to ensure that it is valid where it is at, currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want valid dates, you'll need to validate each keypress. Not a tiger I'd like to tackle personally. If you're not afraid of JavaScript (or JQuery), why not use a calendar GUI like [Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker)